# Get average of attribute through 'has_many'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two models at play here, a Tab, and a Rating.

A `Tab` `has_many` `Ratings`, and each `Rating` `belongs_to` one `Tab`; each `Rating` has a `value` between 1 and 5.

Here are my models, with the relevant code:

**tab.rb**

```
class Tab < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

**rating.rb**

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :tab
  ...
end
```

And this is how my index view is displayed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmSo.png]

with the `Rating` column being the average rating value of the tab.

Right now, to get each tab's average rating, I'm executing a query for each tab's average rating. This is very slow, and I am looking to improve this.

Here's my controller, with the relevant method as it is:

**tabs_controller.rb**

```
class TabsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    # need to display average rating
    # don't want to do one query for each tab
    # so, make index return a table that includes avg rating as a column
    @tabs = Tab.all
  end
  ...
end
```

These are all the queries generated when I load the tab `index` page:

[image]

I think that I will need to execute a query in the `index` controller method that returns a table including all the tabs, and the average rating of each of those tabs. How would I do this?

I might also need to use a view. If anyone could lead me in the right direction, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the current code in the index?

Comment: @gates sorry, edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this. this will work

```
Tab.joins(:ratings).select("tabs.*, AVG(ratings.value) AS average_ratings").group("tab.id")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I'm just bad with understanding how "group" works, I had the first part of that query before but I just couldn't quite finish it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jQuery Raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) before [here](http://resturants.herokuapp.com/).

To compute average rating in your TabsController show action you can add this

```
...
@ratings = Rating.where(tab_id: @tab.id)
if @tab.ratings.any?
    @avg_rating=@tabs.average(:value).round(2)
 else
    @avg_rating=0
end


...
```

and to display it in show page

```
<div class="start-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_rating %> ></div>
```

but in the index page, do this

```
<div class="start-rating" data-score= <%= tab.ratings.average(:value) %> > </div>
```